# How to pass param from controller to layout in YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to send a parameter from controller to layout (i.e. main.php). But I am not able to get the param in main.php

I tried:

Controller Code:

```
$this->render('index',array('param' => $paramValue));
```

And this is how i was trying to get this in layout ie. main.php

1. `$this->param` (as in yii 1)
2. `$param`

But i am not able to get param value in layout. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#creating-layouts you shoulld reread manual and look at `->beginContent()` method.

Comment: You can use $this->context to do this. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60463356/884177

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[yii\base\View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html) has special [$params](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$params-detail) property.

For example it's used for building breadcrumbs in default generated CRUD code templates with Gii.

You can set it like this before rendering:

```
use Yii;

Yii::$app->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

Inside a controller you can set it like this:

```
$this->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

Then it will be available in views (including main layout):

```
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

echo $this->params['customParam'];
```

You can also find it in [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#sharing-data-among-views).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you some steps for this problem.

1. pass parameter to view file
2. Set parameter to view parameter
3. Check For parameter and If exist then use it.

   ```
   //in controller method
   $this->render("view-file-name",["paramName" => "some parameter"]);

   //in view file for eg: index.php
   //i'm passing paremeter sent form controller's action to view params.
   $this->params["paramFromViewFile"] = $paramName; //here $paramName is the parameter we sent from controller's method

   //access parameter sent from view file
   if($this->params && !empty($this->params["paramFromViewFile"]))
   {
        echo $this->params["paramFromViewFile"];  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In Yii2 you can access your controller object from a view using `$this->context` for example if in your controller you set a parameter like this:

```
public $title = 'My custom title';
```

Then in your layout you can read it like this:

```
$this->context->title
```

It is explained in Yii documentation in section: [Accessing Data in Views](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#accessing-data-in-views)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are rendering `index.php` view, not the `main.php` one.

And `$param` this is how you get it in 1.1 version.

UPD: If you want a param in your `main.php` layout declare it in your `Controller` class, and then you will be able to get it `$this->param` this way.

UPD2: Looks like in 2.0 version you need to declare param in a yii\web\View class. And access it via `Yii::$app->view->param`.

Comment: main.php is main layout file. We never need to render that file

Comment: I have already tried this and getting error like : "Getting unknown property: yii\web\View::param"

Answer (score 0):

directly calling $param u should get the value, try

```
in controller declare a $param,
public $param = '';

then in the acction do
$param='haha';

in layout
echo $this->param;
```

Comment: use $this->controller->param

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, I resolve that in:

1. **In my Controller par exemple, I do that**

   `$this->view->params['typeUser'] = 'Internaut';`
2. **in my View**

   `$this->params['typeUser'] or echo $this->params['typeUser']`