# yii2 correct application architecture (pass data to layout)

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i need to send data from controllers to main layout (something like notifier of a new messages in top menu) i need it in all app(global)

i found one way to to pass variables to layout

```
Yii::$app->controller->myvar
```

from class property to layout, but i think it's not best way to duplicate code to all controllers, maybe i suppose to extend base Controller and set my logic here?

Tell me please the best practice to do what i want.

ps. Tnx and sorry for my English

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038912/how-to-pass-param-from-controller-to-layout-in-yii2

Comment: Why you just dont use global app params
    Yii::$app->params['foo'] = 'bar'; // controller
and
    echo Yii::$app->params['foo']; // in view/layout/elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

In the controller, you can use

```
$this->view->params['name'] = 123
```

and in the layout

```
<?= $this->params['name'] ?>
```

Comment: duplicate my logic to all controllers?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use yii global app params

```
Yii::$app->params['foo'] = 'bar'; // controller
```

and

```
echo Yii::$app->params['foo']; // in view/layout/controllers/elsewhere
```

2) You can use session. Create a controller, that will be extended by others, with these 3 functions:

```
<?php
namespace common\components;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Set user flash notice
     * @param $message
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setFlash($key, $message){
        return Yii::$app->session->setFlash($key, $message);
    }

    /**
     * Has user flash notice
     * @param $message
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function hasFlash($key){
        if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash($key)) return True;
        else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get user flash notice
     * @param $message
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFlash($key){
        return Yii::$app->session->getFlash($key);
    }
}
```

now in your controllers

```
use common\components\BaseController;
...
class MyController extends BaseController
...
$this->setFlash('foo','bar'); // setting flash var
```

and in your views

```
echo $this->context->getFlash('foo'); // getting flash var
```

or

```
echo Yii::$app->controller->getFlash('foo'); // getting flash var
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line add in config\main.php

### 'user'=>array( 'class'=>'WebUser', // enable cookie-based authentication 'allowAutoLogin'=>true, ),

After that create new file in protected\components\WebUser.php, In this WebUser.php file

class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
    private $_model;

```
function Update()
{
    return $this->myvar='this is my variable';
}
```

}

You can access in layout file like this echo Yii::app()->user->update();

Comment: The question is about Yii2, not Yii1.