# Can't get params in view passed by render. Yii2

Tags: php, view, yii2, render

I'm rendering another view in my view.

```
use yii\base\View;
    echo $this->render('current-view',array('test'=>'teeest'));
```

Now in other view - `current-view.php` I want to get access to this parametres:

```
use yii\base\View;
var_dump($params);
var_dump(Yii::$app->view->params);
```

`$params` returns `Null` and `$app->view->params` returns empty array. As I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038912/how-to-pass-param-from-controller-to-layout-in-yii2) proper solution is second one, but why array is empty then? What I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For see th content of you var you should use

```
var_dump($test);
```

you have passed 'test' in you render and then in view you should have $test